# Change all section headings' colour while using memoir

Tags: sectioning, color, memoir, sectsty

I recently converted a document from `book` to `memoir`. It turns out that `sectsty` is incompatible. I used to have this:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\color{blue}}
```

which very conveniently changed all my section headings' colours, including chapter, sections and subsections. What's the closest I can get for `memoir`?

Comment: A solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578046/8668352) that colors only the titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memoir` class provides plenty of hooks for doing this sort of thing, but chapters and sections are treated differently. The `\printchaptername` macro prints the chapter name. Since we don't want to redefine it, I have used the `\addtodef` macro to prepend the `\color` macro to its definition, leaving the rest unchanged.

Depending on how you want the Table of Contents to look like, there are two different macros that can be changed. If you only want the TOC title changed, a different patching macro `\addtoiargdef` is used, since that macro takes an argument and cannot be patched with `addtodef`.

For the section formatting, there is an empty hook for each sectioning level which is initially set to `{}`. There is a macro `\setSstyle` (where `S` stands for the sectioning level (`sec`, `subsec`, `subsubsec`).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtodef{\printchaptername}{\color{blue!50!black}}{}
\addtodef{\tocheadstart}{\color{blue!50!black}}{} % If you want the whole TOC to be blue also
%\addtoiargdef{\printtoctitle}{\color{blue!50!black}}{} % If you just want the TOC title blue
\setsecheadstyle{\color{blue!50!black}}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\color{blue!50!black}}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output]

Comment: If I add “some text” between each sectionning command, only the one after `\chapter{A chapter}` appears in black…

Comment: @NBur Thanks for pointing this out. It's odd the OP accepted it with not comment. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Adding the `\setsubsecstyle{\color{blue!50!black}}` changes nothing here :(
As mentionned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578046/8668352, I use `\set<(sub)(sub)sec/(sub)para>headstyle{\sffamily\color{red}}` instead in cunjunction with `\renewcommand{\<part/chapter>namefont}{<decl>}`, 
`\renewcommand{\<part/chapter>numfont}{<decl>}` and `\renewcommand{\<part/chapter>titlefont}{<decl>}`

Comment: @NBur Sorry that was a typo in my correction. I should have copied the code I tested. :)