# Change color of starred chapter headings

Tags: sectioning, chapters, memoir, starred-version

I want to make chapter headings colorful in a memoir. I've tried the approach proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339037/change-all-section-headings-colour-while-using-memoir/339044#339044). The only problem with this solution is that the unnumbered chapters remain unchanged. Is there a starred version of `\printchaptername`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtodef{\printchaptername}{\color{red}}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Foo}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Bar}
\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: always make a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer : Done

Comment: redefine `\chaptitlefont`, `\chapnumfont` and `\chapnamefont`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtodef{\printchaptername}{\color{red}}{}

\addtodef{\printchapternonum}{\color{red}}{} % this takes care of unnumbered chapters

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter*{Foo}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    \chapter{Bar}
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]